# keeping background stretched to bottom even when filtering

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list of results on a webpage, and I've implemented filtering on that list. In order to keep the background color of the results div stretched to the bottom even when there are no (or few) results, I'm using the following snippet of javascript:

```
var window_height = $(window).height();
var header = $('.header').height();
var search = $('.search').height();
var footer = $('.footer').height();
var total_height = window_height - header - search - footer;
var div_height = $('#results-container').height();

if (div_height < total_height) {
    $('#results-container').height(total_height);
}
```

This part works. What doesn't work is when I un-filter the results and the list gets longer again. At this point, div_height remains the height of total_height, and my div ends early (and my footer shows up in the middle of the results). If I comment out the last three lines, the div expands and contracts properly (but ends prematurely, hence the need to do something to force it to the footer).

Googling suggests that there isn't a way to do this with CSS, but I'm not sure if javascript is really the answer either.

The footer has a set height, the other aspects do not.

Comment: What happens if you use the `scrollHeight` of the result container as value for `div_height`?

Comment: Same behaviour. But thanks.

Comment: But you do run the script again after unfiltering, right? And the results are children of the container?

Answer (score 0):

statcic `min-height`

```
#results-container {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

dynamic `min-height` based on window height

```
//assuming `header` `search` and `footer` has static height
// and some of those 3 heights are 200px;
#results-container {
    min-height: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working. When there are no results, the background ends *way* prematurely.

Comment: 100% could probably be replaced with 100vh. Just be aware that calc and vh might not work across all browsers...

Comment: That did it! Thanks!